# Safest way to apply changes recommended by sql query on CRM Dynamics

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to CRM, trying to help our CRM team to make our CRM application faster. We have on-premises 2015 version.

I ran the stats query on CRM DB, there are more than 1000 indexes having more 30% avg_fragmentation.

what is safest way to resolve this issue? can we do this in Live CRM DB or can we create a copy of Live CRM DB and do on the live again? and another question is how to create live copy and manage in such way so that whenever main DB is down it goes to live copy and keep application running?

PLEASE Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating and de-fragmenting indexes on the CRM database are supported operations.  Microsoft recommends that indexes with a fragmentation level greater than 30% be rebuilt, while those with greater than 10% fragmentation should be reorganized.

Defragmenting your production indexes is perfectly safe but you should run the operation overnight to minimize any affect on system performance.

Comment: Thanks Zach! for your guidance.